# Show raw bytes that make up an attribute in a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, encoding

I am processing shapefiles, and I'm trying to track down an encoding problem. I want to check the raw bytes of an attribute to see if this shapefile (and hence the step that created it) is the source of the problem.

If I have a shapefile, how can I print out the raw bytes for attribute X for the object which has attribute Y = Z? e.g. I suspect that the row `ID=12` has a 'bad' encoding for the `NAME` field. How can I print out the raw bytes (e.g. a hexidecimal format or `od -c` format, or ...) that make up the `NAME` field for the object in the shapefile with `ID=12`? If it's only possible to print out all attributes for that object that's OK (There aren't many and I can visually search for what I want).

Preferably with open source tools / things installable on ubuntu, and preferably on the command line.

Comment: You can do this with `od` and a dBase III file format description, or write a 5-10 line 'C' or Python program.

Answer (score 3):

Printing out the raw bytes isn't the problem. The issue is knowing where to look in the byte stream for the data you want.  The dBase-III+ format used in shapefiles is documented in many places.  It starts with a 32-byte header, then has one 32-byte field descriptor for each field, then a 1-byte terminator, then has N bytes for each record, the first of which is a deletion flag (the number of records and the length of each record are stored in the first 12 bytes).

Quoting a piece of the [xBase documentation](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_STRUCT):

```
00h /   0| Version number      *1|  ^
         |-----------------------|  |
01h /   1| Date of last update   |  |
02h /   2|      YYMMDD        *21|  |
03h /   3|                    *14|  |
         |-----------------------|  |
04h /   4| Number of records     | Record
05h /   5| in data file          | header
06h /   6| ( 32 bits )        *14|  |
07h /   7|                       |  |
         |-----------------------|  |
08h /   8| Length of header   *14|  |
09h /   9| structure ( 16 bits ) |  |
         |-----------------------|  |
0Ah /  10| Length of each record |  |
0Bh /  11| ( 16 bits )     *2 *14|  |
```

Then you just need to figure out where record 12 starts, and how long it is, and use the `-j` / `--skip-bytes=BYTES` and  `-N` / `--read-bytes=BYTES` flags of `od` to restrict the output to the suspect row.

Scripting a generic solution to parse the little-endian short words for header and record length and displaying a single row is possible in only a dozen lines of code.

I whipped up a slightly more involved script, but can't convince the GSE editor
to allow more than an image:
[image: dbfDump.sh]

Note that I'm skipping the first byte of the actual record (which is a "marked as deleted" flag that's always a space in shapefiles).